# How do I use PHP-apis to get data into Django pages?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a PHP-api providing me the following data:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 0,
    "SubErrorCode": 0,
    "ErrorMessage": "",
    "Data": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "news_title": "Recent Update",
                    "news_description": "last month articles",
                    "image_id": 2,
                    "news_date": "2018-04-01",
                    "news_content": "the big content",
                    "slug": "recent-update1",
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1
                }
            ]
}
```

I want to create a view in Django that accepts data from API and displays it on a page.

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def blog_last_month(request):
headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + "token"
    }
    response=requests.get("/url",headers=headers,verify=False)
    data=response.json()
    return render(request,"blogHome.html",{"title":data['title']})
```

How do I access the nested Json object elements?

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: You have a mistake: `response=request.get("/guest/news/selector/last_month")` you use `request` but you need to use `requests` library.

Comment: Check my Updated code for error and a few modifications. The code is still not functional